# Stop users from tabbing to controls on my application

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way I can stop users from tabbing to items on my application using C# winforms? I tried setting their `TabIndex` to values above 100 but that didnt work, they still acted as if they were the lowest index thats not set.

**EDIT**

The possible duplicate questions all have `TabStop` set to false as the answer but not all tools have a tab stop property

Comment: Now that you have the how to do it - why would you want to make it harder for users to use your application?

Comment: @Bridge its for items i dont want them to tab to like group boxes

Comment: @WhatsThePoint All the property changes are done by code even by the IDE. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43516946/2408342).

Comment: @WhatsThePoint - regarding your edit - the question linked is still a duplicate, the answers there also address your question about controls which do not have a `TabStop` property.

Comment: @Bridge a different question was originally posted for the duplicatate, a the current one was marked after edit

Comment: Fine - just checking that you have an answer that works for you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try change the TabStop property to false, or set TabIndex to -1

Answer (score 3):

Set the `TabStop` property to `false`.

[image: tabStop]

---

**EDIT**

In the case that your tool does not have the `TabStop` Property you can try doing it by adding this code.

```
this.button1.TabStop = false;
```